# Search a question mark

Tags: google-sheets, worksheet-function

Could anyone help me with this?

I need a formula to do something like this:

```
     =sum(if(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("a?",B8)),15%,0%)+sum(if(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("a",$B8)),90%,0%)
```

The values in `B8` will be `a/a?/a` so the result need to be `195%`

Thank you in advance!

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CKCmZ_oDtu4SHPQApO9f11SeuChzpX8Ry2sLfBRyQ6k/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a table in column `H` with codes and `I` with values:

```
 =ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(VLOOKUP(SPLIT(B8,"/"), $H$1:$I$12,2,0)))
```

**EDIT**:

If question mark is the only differentiating point, then there's no need of a table. To search a question mark, you need to use `~` before the question mark:

```
 =ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(IF(ISERR(SEARCH("~?",SPLIT(B8,"/"))),90%,15%)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use FIND instead of SEARCH. FIND is a literal match.

Comment: not working, will find a simple "a?"  2 times, once at a and once at a? and will count it as 105%

Comment: I think I see. You need to count and multiply?
`=(countif(split($B8, "/"), "a?") * 15%)+(countif(split($B8, "/"), "a") * 90%)`